# Fitting and improving sentiment classifier

Tags: r, machine-learning, tree, svm, sentiment-analysis

Hello I'm trying to build a classifier which has to recognize tweets with negative sentiment (manually labeled with -1) and with positive sentiment (1). I have tried to fit different models of Supervised Methods on my sample data (about 1800 tweets), with a training set composed of 70% of my sample and a test set composed of the remaining part. The problem is that the results obtained are unsatisfying because I obtain high test errors and low AUC values. So where is the problem? Is there a way to improve these results? My sample is avaiable here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9DO29WohGN6eHM3UTM1OUdWVnM. Below I report my analysis step by step, so it is totally reproducible, and the main results:

```
##reading csv
tweets = read.csv2("Finale2.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(tweets)
tweets$Negative= as.factor(tweets$Sent<=-1)
table(tweets$Negative)   
###pre-processing steps
install.packages("tm")
install.packages("SnowballC")
library(tm)
library(SnowballC)
###create a corpus of words and edit it
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(tweets$Tweet))
corpus=tm_map(corpus,tolower)
corpus = tm_map(corpus, PlainTextDocument)
corpus = tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
corpus = tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
corpus=tm_map(corpus,removeWords, stopwords("english")) 
corpus=tm_map(corpus,removeWords,c("RT","rt","https*"))
corpus=tm_map(corpus,stripWhitespace) 
##stemming
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stemDocument)
##creating a matrix of word frequencies
###creazione matrice frequenza parole
DTM <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
DTM
##remove sparse terms
sparse = removeSparseTerms(DTM, 0.995)
###convert the sparse matrix into a dataframe 
tweetsSparse <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(sparse))
names(tweetsSparse)
###make all variables R friendly
colnames(tweetsSparse) <- make.names(colnames(tweetsSparse))
##add indipendent variables 
tweetsSparse$Negative <- tweets$Negative
###loading package caTools
install.packages("caTools")
library(caTools)
###splitting training set and test set
set.seed(234)
splitNegative <- sample.split(tweetsSparse$Negative, SplitRatio = 0.7)
trainSparse <- subset(tweetsSparse, splitNegative == TRUE)
testSparse <- subset(tweetsSparse, splitNegative == FALSE)
```

#### Models

1-LINEAR DISCRIMINANT ANALYSIS

```
require(MASS)
library(MASS)
lda.fit = lda(Negative ~., trainSparse)
lda.fit
###prediction on the test set
lda.pred=predict(lda.fit,testSparse)
table(testSparse$Negative,lda.pred$class)

       FALSE TRUE
  FALSE   134  119
  TRUE    123  176
 testerror=(134+119)/nrow(testSparse)
 testerror
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwTun.png) 0.4583333

```
####ROC CURVE
install.packages("ROCR")
library(ROCR)
pred <- prediction(lda.pred$posterior[,2], testSparse$Negative) 
perf <- performance(pred,"tpr","fpr")
plot(perf,colorize=TRUE)
abline(0, 1, lty = 2)
```

[image]

```
as.numeric(performance(pred, "auc")@y.values)
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwTun.png) 0.598411

#### 2-LASSO MODEL

```
install.packages("glmnet")
library(glmnet)
##create the x matrix and the y vector for the training and test set errors (controllare)
x.train = model.matrix(Negative ~ . -1, data = trainSparse)
y.train=trainSparse$Negative
x.test = model.matrix(Negative ~ . -1, data = testSparse)
y.test=testSparse$Negative
##lasso logistic model
sent.lasso = glmnet(x.train, y.train, family = "binomial")
plot(sent.lasso, xvar = "lambda", label = TRUE)
sent.lasso
##select the best lambda with 10-CV:
cv.lasso=cv.glmnet(x.train,y.train,family="binomial")
plot(cv.lasso)
coef(cv.lasso)
###using the best model to predict on the test set 
pred.lasso = predict(cv.lasso, x.test, s = cv.lasso$lambda.1se, type = "class")
table(testSparse$Negative, pred.lasso)
   pred.lasso
        FALSE TRUE
  FALSE    40  213
  TRUE     18  281
lassoerror=(213+18)/nrow(testSparse)
lassoerror
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwTun.png) 0.4184783

```
###ROC lasso
prob.lasso = predict(cv.lasso, x.test, s = cv.lasso$lambda.1se, type = "response")
predob = prediction(prob.lasso, testSparse$Negative)
perf = performance(predob, "tpr", "fpr")
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
plot(perf, main = "LASSO Logistic Regression")
plot(perf, colorize = TRUE)
plot(perf, colorize = TRUE, print.cutoffs.at = seq(0, 1, by = 0.1), text.adj = c(-0.2, 1.7))
abline(0, 1, lty = 2)
```

[image]

```
as.numeric(performance(predob, "auc")@y.values)
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwTun.png) 0.6266673

#### 3-CLASSIFICATION TREE

```
install.packages("tree")
library(tree)
sent.tree = tree(Negative ~ ., data = trainSparse)
summary(sent.tree)
plot(sent.tree)
text(sent.tree,pretty=0)
```

[image]

Here I have doubts about tree interpretation and the number of nodes is very poor.

```
set.seed(2)
tree.pred = predict(sent.tree, testSparse, type = "class")
table(testSparse$Negative, tree.pred)

   tree.pred
        FALSE TRUE
  FALSE    14  239
  TRUE      5  294
> treerror=(239+5)/nrow(testSparse)
> treerror
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwTun.png) 0.442029

```
##Roc
tree.pred = predict(sent.tree, testSparse, type = "vector") # predict probabilities    
library(ROCR)
pred <- prediction(tree.pred[,2], testSparse$Negative) 
perf <- performance(pred,"tpr","fpr")
plot(perf,colorize=TRUE)
```

[image]

```
as.numeric(performance(pred, "auc")@y.values)
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwTun.png) 0.5195381

VERY VERY BAD!!

#### 4-Random Forest

```
install.packages("randomForest")
library(randomForest)
set.seed(345)
sent.rf = randomForest(Negative ~ ., data = trainSparse)
sent.rf
##plot the error rate
plot(sent.rf$err.rate[,1])
###variable importance plot
varImpPlot(sent.rf)
###preformance on the test set
rf.pred = predict(sent.rf, testSparse, type = "class")
table(testSparse$Negative, rf.pred)

  rf.pred
        FALSE TRUE
  FALSE   162   91
  TRUE    119  180

rferror=(119+91)/nrow(testSparse)
rferror
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwTun.png) 0.3804348
In this case I'm not able to compute the ROC curve so please if someone knows how to do it, please supply the code.

#### 5-Support vector models

```
###Support vector Classifier
install.packages("e1071")
library(e1071)
svmfit = svm(as.factor(Negative) ~ ., data = trainSparse, kernel = "linear", cost = 1)
names(svmfit)
summary(svmfit)
svmfit$index
##selecting best SVC with 10 CV
set.seed(1)
tune.out=tune(svm ,Negative~.,data=trainSparse, kernel ="linear",
              ranges=list(cost=c(0.1,1,10,100,1000),probability = TRUE))
```

In this case I have a Warning: Max number of iterations reached. If someone knows how to solve this please, help me. The same problem appears also with a polynomial kernel.

#### Radial kernel

```
tune.out=tune(svm ,Negative~.,data=trainSparse, kernel ="radial",
              ranges=list(cost=c(0.1,1,10,100,1000),gamma=c(0.5,1,2,3,4), 
                          probability = TRUE)) 
summary(tune.out)
best=tune.out$best.model
###prediction on the test set
svm.pred = predict(best, testSparse, type = "class")
table(testSparse$Negative,svm.pred)

 svm.pred
        FALSE TRUE
  FALSE    30  223
  TRUE      5  294

radialerror=(223+5)/nrow(testSparse)
 radialerror
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwTun.png) 0.4130435

```
###Roc curve
yhat.opt = predict(best,testSparse,probability = TRUE)
pred <- prediction(attributes(yhat.opt)$probabilities[,2], testSparse$Negative) 
perf <- performance(pred,"tpr","fpr")
plot(perf,colorize=TRUE)
```

[image]

```
as.numeric(performance(pred, "auc")@y.values)
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwTun.png) 0.5908827

Well, hoping that this could be a useful example for someone and not be blocked. If someone can help me to improve these results or solve also one of these problems, please comment below.

Comment: This question is not appropriate on SO, which is a forum for focused questions on programming problems. Please remove this question and ask it on [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @mac gionny i think your training data don't carry strong sentiments, for example, `Turns out Brexit does not even mean breakfast` is labeled as `-1` whereas `Anti-Brexit traitors outed on twitter` is labeled as `1`. I think there is a lot of noise in  the labelled data, you may consider preprocessing data / remove some sentences that are outliers, also the word features that are confusing the classifiers. Another thing to try is to consider more features (such as bigram) or some shallow parser (e.g., stanford dependency parser) to get some more features.

Comment: ok tank you @SandipanDey, this is because I wanted to do a binary classification and so I have unified tweets with a neutral sentiment with the others as reccomended by my professor...please have you a solution for the warning of the linear svm? Or to compute roc curve with random forest?

Comment: I've voted to move it, but it will take more votes. If you're blocked, you should try to improve the questions that you have asked over there in the hope that such improvements will add some upvotes.

Comment: @mac gionny: for neutral you should add 0 label (in that it would be 3-class classification). Also you want ROC curve for randomForest right? what warning are you getting for linear svm?

Comment: Yes @SandipanDey the code for the Roc curve of the Random Forest.... Anyway I had labeled also with 0...but my prof suggested me to do a binary classification ....the warning of svm is written in the point 5, is relative to the reaching of the max number of iterations...

Comment: I did not downvote. I did vote to migrate your question. However, more votes are needed before it can be migrated.

Comment: @SandipanDey  thank you for availability...Is that last Roc curve bad in your opinion?

Comment: it's not that bad.

Comment: @SandipanDey I don't  know how shallow parser operate... do you have an example, to apply it in R?

Answer (score 0):

For `Random Forest ROC` try this:

```
rf.pred = predict(sent.rf, testSparse, type = "prob")
pred <- prediction(rf.pred[,2], testSparse$Negative) 
perf <- performance(pred,"tpr","fpr")
plot(perf,colorize=TRUE)
abline(0, 1, lty = 2)
as.numeric(performance(pred, "auc")@y.values)
```

[image]